# Is a UISplitViewController always embedded into a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am developing an application using the new adaptive layout.

The application for the iPhone and iPad are identical for the first 2 screens. They are just bog standard views.

However I then need to have the application to go to a splitView controller. On the iPhone it will be a tableview that then displays the data. On the iPad it will be a split view.

My story board consists of a UIViewController embedded into a UINavigationController which contains a containerView. This then links to the splitViewController which with the new adaptive layout will handle whether to use contained or regular.

Here is a picture:

[image]

However when the splitViewController is pushed onto the stack it is embedded in a UINavigationController. What I would like is just the splitView without it being embedded into a UINavigationController. Is this possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Present the split view controller instead of pushing it.

Comment: The answer to your title question is no. In fact, you shouldn't embed a split view controller in a navigation controller. It's your particular storyboard setup that's causing this.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. No matter how I present it, it has it's navigation bar. I have also read that a split view must be the root view. However my first views are not split views. Is there anyway I can have this split view part way through the app? I thought about hiding the master view for the first 2 views but that will probably cause problems when trying to simultaneously do the iPhone with the same storyboard. Do you know of a way to achieve the split view halfway through the application?